# What "WSP1021: Fault "null" not bound. Check names in port and binding definitions." does mean?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

I'm making a soap web services in Java with JAX-WS (Metro stack) and GlassFish/Tomcat as container.

The web service works fine but in the server logs I see a warning:

> Warning:   WSP1021: Fault "null" not bound. Check names in port and binding definitions.

I have searched on google but I really can't understand what that means.

It seems to be relate of each web method that throws an exception.

Someone have some information ?

Comment: It looks to me like you're trying to set up some form of network connection, perhaps a socket, and one of the parameters you are passing in has a null value... As such, when the connection is attempted, it checks if the binding exists, realises that null isn't bound to anything, and dies. If you could provide some context, I might be able to further advise.

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't provide my context. But after I will put some example code. I have some simple methods exposed in the web services that throw a costum exception. But all works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. The problem was in the "wsit-[package].[webServiceClass].xml" configuration file. There were old operation name with an empty `<fault/>` tag.

These operations were renamed but NetBeans 8.0.2 didn't delete the entries in the wsit configuration file.

Once deleted these old operations the warnings disappear.